# GCE load balancer can not call from inside

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I use CoreOS on Google Compute Engine, to launch 3 instances: core1, core2, core3

I use Fleet to start a web service container on one of the three instances (ex: core1).
Because I don't know which machine the container is on, so I use Network Load Balance to forward request to the container, with the Targer Pool contain 3 machines

The issue is that I can not curl the load balancer IP from the core2 or core3 machine.
I expect the load balancer should forward the request to web serivce container on core1. How do I do that?